# Dynamic message on onclick confirm() without passing value

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, hyperlink

Using `href`, I want to display the value of `itemName` on the message of confirm() but pass `itemId`. Here is the code:

```
<a href="del.jsp?itemID=<%=itemID%>"
    onclick="return confirm('Continue to delete employee: ' + 
    <%=itemName%> + '?');">
    Delete
</a>
```

But this doesn't work. If I change `itemName` to `itemID`, it works fine. I read that by concatenating, you are passing the value of the variable you concatenated, but what I want to display is the name. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As that's serverside code, you don't need to concatenate it in javascript, just insert it directly

```
<a href="del.jsp?itemID=<%=itemID%>"
    onclick="return confirm('Continue to delete employee: <%=itemName%>?');">
    Delete
</a>
```